# React Router Dom one route outside of nest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hopefully this has a simple answer but I haven't found anyone else asking this: I'm just trying to create a route hierarchy with one route (the signin page in this case) that lives outside of a wrapper, and every other route living inside said wrapper (which has header/sidebar/etc). I'm using react 16.0.0 + react-router-dom 4.2.2 and my futile attempt to get things working is

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Wrapper from './components/common/Wrapper';
import App from './components/App';
import HomePage from './components/Home';
import SignInUpPage from './components/SignInUp';
import DistrictsPage from './components/Districts';
import StudioPage from './components/Studio';
import CollectionsPage from './components/Collections';


export default (
  <Wrapper>
    <Route path="/account" component={SignInUpPage} />
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/districts" component={DistrictsPage} />
        <Route path="/studio" component={StudioPage} />
        <Route path="/collections" component={CollectionsPage} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Wrapper>

);
```

But obviously this just renders the app component below the signin, same result if I nest the App component within the Switch. Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render your **App** component only if **/account** doesn’t match:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/account" component={ SignInUpPage } />
    <Route path="/" component={ App } />
  </Switch>
</Wrapper>
```

...and then move your other routes inside your **App** component:

*App.js*

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
  <Route path="/districts" component={ DistrictsPage } />
  <Route path="/studio" component={ StudioPage } />
  <Route path="/collections" component={ CollectionsPage } />
</Switch>
```

I’m assuming from your code that **Wrapper** is to wrap everything and **App** is only to wrap the nested routes. You can switch them around if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Nice! that worked perfectly, I guess I didn't consider routing outside of the router itself...is that a common thing to do or no? Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad this helped. With React Router v4, you put your sub routes inside your components.